# How to fix Outlook design?

Tags: css, outlook-2013

I am using exact 2013 Outlook design changes.

But it does not work

```
  <!--[if gt mso 14]>
    <style type="text/css">
    .outlook{ background-color:#F00;}
   </style>
  <![endif]-->
```

Comment: How are you sending your emails? through a third party service (sometimes they will strip the content)? is your `<style>` block in the `<head>` or `<body>`? What DOM element is `.outlook`, a `<table>`?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you use the wrong version of outlook:

```
Outlook 2000 - Version 9 
Outlook 2002 - Version 10
Outlook 2003 - Version 11
Outlook 2007 - Version 12
Outlook 2010 - Version 14
Outlook 2013 - Version 15
```